# Cambiar y enviar el valor de una variable de otra clase con intent

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Quisiera cambiar el valor de una variable de la clase de destino al apretar el botón que me envía a ella, entonces ya la clase abierta tendría una variable con un valor cambiado.

Se me ocurrió algo así pero no funciona:

```
boton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
            
       Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),destino.class);
       variableDeDestino= 2;
       startActivity(intent);

    }
}
```

Comment: Porfavor evita confundir a otros usuarios, pues la etiqueta javascript esta totalmente fuera de contexto en este caso, ya que JavaScript y Java son lenguajes de programacion totalmente diferentes y el uno no tiene nada que ver con el otro, es como comparar ingles con chino, borrare la etiqueta JavaScript de la pregunta, pues esta no tiene nada que ver ahi.

Comment: muy bien, disculpas recién empiezo a aprender.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

envia la informacion en el Intent:

```
boton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
            
       Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),destino.class);
       //variableDeDestino= 2;

       
       intent.putExtra("variable", 2);
       startActivity(intent);

    }
}
```

Dentro del método onCreate() de la Activity destino recibes el valor a partir del nombre de la llave que en este ejemplo seria "variable" :

```
int datoRecibido =0;

Bundle parametros = this.getIntent().getExtras();
 if(parametros !=null){
    datoRecibido = parametros.getInt("variable"); 
 } 

 if(datoRecibido  == 2){
    //realiza algo...
 }
```

Comment: muchas gracias hermano, perdón por molestar no se si me podrías decir como poder usar la variable dato recibido en un if para si es igual 2 ejecute algo.

Comment: He modificado la respuesta, revisa la estructura if al final, ahí puedes llamar un metodo o proocedimiento,

Comment: De esto que me diste, solo modifiqué también getString a getInt. Y funciona perfecto. Muchas gracias por ayudarme el mundo necesita más gente cómo vos.